# Lytro-like functionality from RAW images?

Tags: photoshop, gimp, photography, lytro

I have a bunch of RAW images (.cr2) and a degree is amateur geekery. I want to know if there's a software/plugin/tool/piece of code that can help me change the point of focus of these images much like we can for images taken with a Lytro camera.

I don't know much about RAW images but googling it didn't do much help. Most site's explain that RAW images have a lot of info about the color profile (they're pretty heavy just to have color info!) and so I'm left wondering if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lytro captures rays of light, effectively recording each as light intensity, point of incidence on the front lens, and point of incidence on the sensor plane. So the light intensity function is four dimensional. The software then forms a standard 2d image by mathematically simulating a lens in that light field.

Traditional cameras simply capture the sum total intensity at each point on the sensor. So the light intensity function is two dimensional.

The same amount of information just isn't there. The best you can do is hope you've got a reasonably sharp original image, try to edge detect individual objects and apply a blur elsewhere. That's what the phone app Lytro simulators do — smart phones have very small lenses so on the scale from a pinhole camera up to a hypothetical f/1.0 they're towards the pinhole end.